# Align text without it bleeding into another span tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and my css is giving me some problems.  Here is a simple sample of a problem I have with 2nd span tag causing it to "bleed" or "spill over" into the first span tag.

Now, I cannot use tables with this as that is not what co-workers want ( even though that is certainly what I am certain to not have this problem with).

```
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico"><i class="icon-flag"></i></span>
            <span class="text">Login</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
            <span class="testthis">
              Register your contact information, background and expertise
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want is certainly to wrap the text, but the word "expertise" should (needs to) go directly under the word "Register" and NOT end up to the far left under the first span tag with the icon-pencil" class

[image]

Comment: And your CSS so far is?

Comment: Bootstrap, but I realize too many other styles are missing in order to make it easy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GgzZC/) let's check if it works for you.

```
.nav {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-top:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-left:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    border-right:1px solid #E1E1E1;

    }
.nav li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    list-style-type:disc outside !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    position:relative;
    }
.nav li a {
    color:#3D4451;
    }
.nav li a span.ico {
    width:33px;
    height:33px;
    border-right:1px solid #E1E1E1;
    background-color:#E9E8E8;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
.nav li a span.text {
    padding:5px 5px 5px 0;
    margin-left:40px;
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: That is an impressive amount of code that required some reverse engineering.  I added in the bootstrap code to the jsfiddle,  one issue I have is that is the css is a bit invasive in that it affects too many other elements on the page,  i'm still playing with it

Comment: NICE!!   Ok,  only thing other than adding bootstrap to jsfiddle was that I edited the  .nav li a span.ico {
    width:33px;    to have a width of -->  width:13px;   This is NOT your fault as jsfiddle showed it to be fine,  but in my "live" application I had to do that.   Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way by specifying `text-indent` on the anchor tags in `li`, it can make it look like how you want it to be.

```
li a {
    text-indent: -16px; /* This of course is the calculated width of span.ico */
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6jvX6/)**

More precisely, make it affect only the anchors directly under a `li` inside a `.nav` element:

```
.nav li > a {
    text-indent: -16px;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work ( neither)  I ended up losing the left border of the flag and pencil icon by doing that.   I can see what you are doing, is there another way to "contain" the text" within nested "containers"  (divs or something) ?

Comment: @CoreStone Yup have no clue of your css. so i provided solution based on what you have in your question.